# Large data processing in salesforce

Tags: batch

I was trying to find out some other ways of processing data other than batch apex. But most of information getting only about using batch apex. Is there any other way to process large data synchronous/asynchronously in salesforce other than batch apex?

Comment: can u provide some specifics, wats the volume u r looking at.. ? is it just processing records for one particular object or a group of related objects ? do u face any issues in using batch apex ?

Comment: Batch apex is taking too much time to complete, so i was looking for an alternative to batch apex.

Comment: "Too much time" is not specific enough. What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? The answer to your question will vary greatly depending on the actual requirements. On the one hand, you could use a trigger to synchronously process each record as it is modified; or you could use asynchronous @future calls; or you could create an external application that makes API calls; or you could use an ETL tool ... what are you trying to accomplish here?